# Angular & Spring - Headers not passed to backend

Tags: angular, spring, http, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to add an Authorization header in my http request from my Angular front-end, but it's not working : the backend don't receive this header.

When I watch on Chrome's console, I can see that the request is containing the header.
When I use Postman, the headers are okay in the backend.

Here is the Postman screenshot :
[image]

Here is my Angular Interceptor :

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            if (!request.url.startsWith('http')) {
               if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                 let headers: HttpHeaders = request.headers;
                 headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
                 localStorage.getItem('token'));

                 request = request.clone({
                     url: environment.backendUrl + request.url, headers
                 });
               }
            }

            console.log("headers are : ", request.headers);

            return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((error: 
            HttpErrorResponse) => 
            {
               [...]
            })) as any;
   }
```

And here is my Spring filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    // Assume we have only one Authorization header value
    final Optional<String> token = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
    // Optional is empty
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Not sure if tihs helps, but I use : 
request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    foo: bar
                }
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was on the `WebSecurityConfig`, I forgot to enable the CORS with this :

```
http
      .cors().and()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add Authorization header key in Access-Control-Allow-Headers(in the backend)

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization (when you give like this it accepts specified headers only.means if you want to accept another key like authorization you have to mention that key name)

or

you can give like this also

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Comment: I think it's not the issue, otherwise I couldn't be able to make this working with Postman. I however added the Spring configuration and it didn't changed anything : registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*");

Comment: i think that is the issue only can you check that once

Comment: i have faced the same issue.front end i am using angular back end i am using spring boot.i checked with soapui it is working but when i run the application it shows the same error.it is working fine after specifying the authorization key in allow headers